# how i can read file with byte inside

Tags: python

I have some file with bytes inside:

```
b'<html lang="en" class="wf-roboto-n4-active wf-roboto-n3-active wf-poppins-n7-active wf-poppins-n4-active wf-poppins-n3-active wf-roboto-n7-active wf-roboto-n5-active wf-sourcecodepro-n5-active wf-poppins-n5-active wf-poppins-n6-active wf-active"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">'
```

And i try to read this file inside unit tetst in 'rb' mode:

```
def test_04_foo(self):
    with open('test_data.txt', 'rb') as reader:
        print(reader.read())

    #some code here
```

And i have b'' in stdout.

How i can get bytes from file?

Comment: This looks like someone put a *string representation* of a bytes object into a text file. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file contains a string representation of a bytes object, so you could solve this by following these questions: [“safe” eval](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4388626/4518341), [Convert bytes to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/606191/4518341) - something like this:

```
import ast

def test_04_foo(self):
    with open('test_data.txt', 'r') as reader:
        b = ast.literal_eval(reader.read())
    s = b.decode('utf-8')
    print(s)
```